# Vue: bind dynamic and static classes

Tags: vue.js

A bit new to Vue so I am looking for a better way(if there's one) to set a default class without using the class attribute twice.

**Component.vue**

```
<template>
    <input class="form__control" :class="class" v-bind="$attrs"/>
<template>

<script>
  export default {
     props: ['class']
}
<script>
```

**Usage**

```
<component class="big-red" data-id="1" type="text"/>
```

Comment: Additionally, if you set a class on the component like your doing it will apply to the component element, input like in your example, so is superfluous to pass a class as a prop, also you could grab the class and apply it somewhere else within the component with `this.classList = this.$el.classList.value; this.$el.classList = []` then on the element `:class="['form__control', classList]"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can bind dynamic and static classes within a single property, using the array declaration:

```
 <template>
    <input :class="['form__control', class]" v-bind="$attrs"/>
<template>
```